# removing duplicate tuples in python

Tags: python

I have a list of 50 numbers, `[0,1,2,...49]` and I would like to create a list of tuples without duplicates, where i define `(a,b)` to be a duplicate of `(b,a)`.  Similarly, I do not want tuples of the form `(a,a)`.

I have this:

```
pairs = set([])
mylist = range(0,50)
for i in mylist:
    for j in mylist:
        pairs.update([(i,j)])

set((a,b) if a<=b else (b,a) for a,b in pairs)
print len(pairs)
>>> 2500
```

I get 2500 whereas I expect to get, i believe, 1225 (n(n-1)/2).

What is wrong?

Comment: Should I be renaming, that is, pairs = set((a,b) if a<=b else (b,a) for a,b in pairs)

Comment: You are not removing the `(a,a)` anywhere among other things..

Comment: I think you want all *combinations*, no?

Comment: `set((a,b) if a<=b else (b,a) for a,b in pairs)`: that does nothing. `pairs` is still the same.

Comment: ah, true, I need to remove the duplicates as well.

Comment: Yes, ok, I think i just forgot to rename pairs.  When I do that, len(pairs) yields 1275, which is 50 greater than I would like.  This probably comes from the fact that I'm not removing duplicates.  Thanks

Comment: Just a mathematical interlude here, you cannot "define" a tuple (a,b) to be a duplicate of (b,a). The fact that they are different from each other is baked into the definition of tuple. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple

Comment: @ASignor sure you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This,

```
pairs = set([])
mylist = range(0,50)
for i in mylist:
    for j in mylist:
        if (i < j):
            pairs.append([(i,j)])

print len(pairs)
```

Comment: You can change the `if` condition to `i < j` (no need for the `i != j` part) - which would be sufficient.

Comment: globally inefficient because it tests for nothing. Better start at the proper index right away. Also the `update` with a list is clumsy (copied from OP code, shouldn't have :))

Answer (score 10):

You want *all combinations*. Python provides a module, `itertools`, with all sorts of combinatorial utilities like this. Where you can, I would stick with using `itertool`, it almost certainly faster and more memory efficient than anything you would cook up yourself. It is also battle-tested. You should not reinvent the wheel.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> combs = list(itertools.combinations(range(50),2))
>>> len(combs)
1225
>>>
```

However, as others have noted, in the case where you have a sequence (i.e. something indexable) such as a list, and you want N choose k, where k=2 the above could simply be implemented by a nested for-loop over the indices, taking care to generate your indices intelligently:

```
>>> result = []
>>> for i in range(len(numbers)):
...     for j in range(i + 1, len(numbers)):
...         result.append((numbers[i], numbers[j]))
...
>>> len(result)
1225
```

However, `itertool.combinations` takes *any iterable*, and also takes a second argument, `r` which deals with cases where k can be something like 7, (and you don't want to write a staircase).

Your approach essentially takes the cartesian product, and then filters. This is inefficient, but if you wanted to do that, the best way is to use `frozensets`:

```
>>> combinations = set()
>>> for i in numbers:
...     for j in numbers:
...         if i != j:
...             combinations.add(frozenset([i,j]))
...
>>> len(combinations)
1225
```

And one more pass to make things tuples:

```
>>> combinations = [tuple(fz) for fz in combinations]
```

Answer (score 2):

problem in your code snippet is that you filter out unwanted values but you don't *assign* back to `pairs` so the length is the same... also: this formula yields the wrong result because it considers `(20,20)` as valid for instance.

But you should just create the proper list at once:

```
pairs = set()

for i in range(0,50):
    for j in range(i+1,50):
        pairs.add((i,j))

print (len(pairs))
```

result:

```
1225
```

With that method you don't even need a `set` since it's guaranteed that you don't have duplicates in the first place:

```
pairs = []

for i in range(0,50):
    for j in range(i+1,50):
        pairs.append((i,j))
```

or using list comprehension:

```
pairs = [(i,j) for i in range(0,50) for j in range(i+1,50)]
```